# React native Build error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

I've updated react-native-firebase to version 5.5.4 but after it I'm unable to build, getting the following error: `error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment`

I use cocoapods to manage the dependencies and my podfile is in the link: https://gist.github.com/thiagoferolla/166f4ba8917bc2fd5d809d0b11c4d72e

The GoogleService-Info.plist is in the correct place and it contains the GOOGLE_APP_ID key-value so I don't know why xcode is throwing this error. Any way to solve it?

Comment: have you found an answer for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

just add the debugger in the Pods/FirebaseCore/FIRApp.m line no 572
and print the appID, it should be for a specific platform only.

might be that would be help.